# GORM return list of list of results or map of results with group by id

Tags: go, go-gorm

Essentially, using GORMDB, my current code looks something like this:

```
res = []*modelExample

DB.Model(&modelExample{}).
        Order("task_id ").
        Find(res)
```

And what I do with res is that I will manually loop through and append the models with the same task_id into one list, and then append this list to be worked on. The reason why I need to do this is because there are some specific operations i need to do on specific columns that I need to extract which I can't do in GORM.

However, is there a way to do this more efficiently where I return like a list of list, which I can then for loop and do my operation on each list element?

Comment: why cant you just use `db.Table().Select().Group()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your needs with the following code snippet:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type modelExample struct {
    TaskId int
    Name   string
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&modelExample{})

    // here you should populate the database with some data

    // querying
    res := make(map[int][]modelExample, 0)
    rows, err := db.Table("model_examples").Select("task_id, name").Rows()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    // scanning
    for rows.Next() {
        var taskId int
        var name string
        rows.Scan(&taskId, &name)
        if _, isFound := res[taskId]; !isFound {
            res[taskId] = []modelExample{{taskId, name}}
            continue
        }
        res[taskId] = append(res[taskId], modelExample{taskId, name})
    }

    // always good idea to check for errors when scanning
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, v := range res {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

After the initial setup, let's take a closer look at the querying section.
First, you're going to get all the records from the table. The records you get are stored in the `rows` variable.
In the `for` loop, you scan all of the records. Each record will be either added as a new map entry or appended to an existing one (if the `taskId` is already present in the map).
This is the easiest way to create different lists based on a specific column (e.g. the `TaskId`). Actually, from what I understood, you need to split the records rather than grouping them with an aggregation function (e.g. `COUNT`, `SUM`, and so on).
The other code I added was just put in for clarity.
Let me know if this solves your issue or if you need something else, thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Was wondering if there is a one-liner in GORM instead of a manually for looping every row?

Comment: AFAIK, this is the only method to scan a result set with more than a row.